# Catch combination Alt, Primary in bash to variable

Tags: bash, variables, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to catch  +  + B (as example) in the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "give your key combination and press <ENTER>:"

read input

echo $input
```

I need B literally as a variable.
 = Ctrl button

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say no. Use a different language. If you're totally desparate you might try one of these [hacks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ReadingFunctionKeysInBash), but I don't endorse them (other than the KEYBD trap, which isn't Bash).